# Redirecting the content of two files

Tags: linux, grep, cat

I want to redirect the content of two files to a single file named `ooo.txt`.

I also want to only take some specific lines of the second file using `grep` (in this case 5 lines before and 25 lines after **'lol'**) WITHOUT using parenthesis

Here's the command that I used:

```bash
cat [file1] &&  cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25 > ooo.txt
```

Unfortunately only the content of the `file 2` is written in the file `ooo.txt` (However the `grep` command is respected).

How can I solve that?

Comment: What do you mean with "WITHOUT using parenthesis"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commands are working exactly as designed.

First:

```
cat [file1]
```

Sends the output of `file1` to `stdout`.

Next:

```
&&
```

Tells it run what comes after if what comes before has an exit status of `0` which it does.

Finally,

```
cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25 > ooo.txt
```

uses the `stdout` out of `cat [file2]` as `stdin` to `grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25` and then uses `> ooo.txt` to redirect that output to the file ooo.txt.

Here are a few methods to get what you are looking for:

The first is just to add a redirect to the first `cat` command and go from there. Assuming the the file either doesn't exist or is empty:

```
cat [file1] > ooo.txt &&  cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25 >> ooo.txt
```

If the file already exists and is not empty and you just want to add to it:

```
cat [file1] >> ooo.txt &&  cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25 >> ooo.txt
```

A less complex command will also work:

```
{ cat [file1]; cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25; } > ooo.txt
```

The curled braces and the `;` between the two `cat` commands and after the `grep` command will redirect the output of all the commands to the file `ooo.txt`. In the case that the contents are to be only added to the file, use `>>` instead of `>`

Comment: Remember what cat is actually short for, as well. Maybe ask op wants is `cat file1 file2`?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I understand but if the entirety of `file1` is wanted and 5 lines before and 25 lines after and including the string `lol` in the second file are wanted, then `cat` on the two files won't work because the string `lol` not appearing at all or on every line in the first file won't achieve what is specified. It would still either only redirect the output of the command after `&&` or give only the matching lines from file1 in addition that.

Comment: @NasirRiley Thanks that's exactly what i was looking for.

Comment: @NasirRiley Sorry to bother you but `{ cat [file1]; cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25 } > ooo.txt` does not seem to work for me nothing happens when i use the command and i have to use CRTL + C to stop the execution any fix for that?

Comment: @Mnako8 There was a typo. See the edit in the answer regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want.

cat [file1] <(cat [file2] | grep  "lol" -B 5 -A 25) > ooo.txt

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The command does work but unfortunatly i don't want to use parenthesis.